# Ionic camera plugin only crops images in 1:1 (square) images

Tags: image, typescript, ionic-framework, crop

I am making an ionic app that requires me to crop images in 16:9 aspect ratio.
So far i can not find any plugin.

I am using ionic camera plugin with the following code

```
var opt : CameraOptions = {
        quality: 20,
        targetWidth:  1920,
        targetHeight: 1080,
        allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY  ,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    };
```

it works fine if the target height and target width are same. but ignores the  target height and target width if they are not same. 
i want the cropped in rectangle shape with 16:9 ratio. is this even available in ionic ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cropper.js it's awesome library for image cropping

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Installation

```
npm install cropperjs
```

Include files:

```
<link  href="/path/to/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/path/to/cropper.js"></script>
```

in Html

```
<div>
  <img id="image" src="picture.jpg">
</div>
```

Now in controller

```
  image = document.getElementById('image');
  var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop: function(e) {
    console.log(e.detail.x);
    console.log(e.detail.y);
    console.log(e.detail.width);
    console.log(e.detail.height);
    console.log(e.detail.rotate);
    console.log(e.detail.scaleX);
    console.log(e.detail.scaleY);
  }
});
```

Comment: Now that's much better. However, since modules are being used and you are installing it from npm, you should import it or require it and remove the script tag. Otherwise this is very good. Downvote removed

Comment: Suggesting `import cropper from 'cropper';` and removing the script tag, will make this very good

Comment: this will only crop from the centre
i want the user to select the part he wants to use in 16:9

Comment: And i dont think this will work in ionic android application.